# Jacoco Gradle Plugin and its dependency on the test task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, jacoco, gradle-plugin

I'm following these docs

https://docs.gradle.org/4.2.1/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

In a java app, with the java plugin enabled, I've added this line to enable the jacoco plugin

apply plugin: 'jacoco'

The docs state

> If the Java plugin is also applied to your project, a new task named jacocoTestReport is created that depends on the test task

So now when I run

`./gradlew build jacocoTestReport`

I can see it kicking off the tests as part of build, but we have some failing tests, so the whole test task reports as failed.

The jacoco code coverage report doesn't generate anything.

If I run

```
./gradlew jacocoTestReport
```

I get a successful report

This may sound like a daft question, but is the reason the first command, `./gradle1 build jacocoTestReport` doesn't generate the report, is because of the failing tests?

Would just `./gradlew build` run the `jacocoTestReport` task if the tests passed?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to "teach a man to fish" rather than give a fish. In that spirit I suggest you add the [task tree plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.dorongold.task-tree) so you can see a visual representation of what's going on for yourself

```
plugins {
  id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "1.3.1"
}
```

You can then try

```
gradle build taskTree
```

and

```
gradle jacocoTestReport taskTree
```

And see what's in the task tree for each

Comment: Thanks @lance-java I will give that a go to further my understanding

Comment: oooh, that's nice, will definitely use that from now on

Answer (score 0):

I've commented out the failing tests and ran ./gradlew build

The remaining tests passed, but no report.

I will have a bash at lance-java's tip for the top, as I do like fishing!

Also going to try ./gradlew build jacocoTestReport

./gradlew build jacocoTestReport is the winner!!

Comment: You could also add something like `check.dependsOn jacocoTestReport` to your build.gradle. This would permanently wire the `jacocoTestReport` task to the "check" lifecycle task (which as you've seen is called by the "build" lifecycle task)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the tests failed.

Adding the following will to build.gradle will ensure that coverage is generated regardless:

```
test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
```